# Python selenium - How would I be able to click on all the buttons on the screen with certain values

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So now I am trying to use selenium to automate a checkout process. However, there are three of the same buttons and I would like to press on all of them. Is there anyway I can do this?

All three buttons have the same class

```
expandButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='expand-collapse']")
expandButton.click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function to find all elements specified by the xpath:

```
expandButtons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='expand-collapse']")
```

This will store a list of all elements matching the xpath in `expandButtons`.
Then you can loop over it by:

```
for button in expandButtons:
    button.click()
```

This will click all buttons that were found.